# How can I redirect to a different URL in Django?

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-urls

I have two pages, one which is to display details for a specific item and another to search for items.  Let's say that the urls.py is properly configured for both of them and within views.py for my app, I have:

```
def item(request, id):
    return render(request, 'item.html', data)

def search(request):
    #use GET to get query parameters
    if len(query)==1:
        #here, I want to redirect my request to item, passing in the id
    return render(request, 'search.html', data)
```

What do I do to properly redirect the request? I've tried `return item(request, id)` and that renders the correct page, but it doesn't change the URL in the address bar.  How can I make it actually redirect instead of just rendering my other page? The URL pattern for the item page is `/item/{id}`.  I've looked at the answer to similar questions on SO and the documentation, but still couldn't figure it out.

Edit: I just started learning Python less than a week ago and the other answer isn't clear enough to help me out.

Edit 2: Nvm, not sure what I did wrong before, but it worked when I tried it again.

Comment: Which "other answer" are you referring to and where exactly are you having trouble? There are hundreds of answers for "Django redirect" on this site, as well as the actual documentation which explains exactly what to do.

Comment: While looking for the other answers again, I retried HttpResponseRedirect and it worked this time. Maybe I had something else broken before that caused it to not redirect.  The original thing I looked at was regarding RedirectViews and I had no idea how that was relevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`HttpResponseRedirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

# ...

return HttpResponseRedirect('/url/url1/')
```

Where "url" and "url1" equals the path to the redirect.

Answer (score 4):

Just minute suggestion from the above answer for the change in import statement

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
return HttpResponseRedirect('/url-name-here/')
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try this :

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
return redirect(f'/customer/{pk}')
```