# Can´t excecute view action in Django

Tags: python, django

I would like to understand why when I click on login button I can't run `user_login` function. I'm new in `django`. Thanks

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from iol_dash import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from iol import Service

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})

def user_login(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    service = Service()
    token = service.get_token(
        username=username,
        password=password
    )
    print(token)
```

index.html:

```
<form class="modal-content animate" method="post" action={{ views.user_login }}>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>
      <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
      <button type="submit">Login</button>

    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define a url for every view. Your `urls.py` should be:

```
from django.urls import path
from iol_dash import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('login',views.user_login,name='user_login')
]
```

And your `index.html` should be in this way:

```
<form class="modal-content animate" method="post" action="{% url 'user_login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>
      <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
      <button type="submit">Login</button>

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works, can you explain why `"{% url 'user_login' %}"` instead of `{{ views.user_login }}`?

Comment: `action` tells when you submit the form, which url it has to redirect. Since, each url has name, it executes the respective `view`

Comment: can you help me with my new issue? Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873691/how-can-i-redirect-to-a-different-url-in-django