# Replace views functions for view class in Django

Tags: python, django

I would like to replace my views functions for a class. I'm new in Django and I try to send `service` object from `user` function to `metrics` function but I can´t do that with `< a href="{% url 'metrics' %}">Metrics</a>` in `home.html`. I don't know how to call a class instead a function too

my code:

```
def user(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    service = Service()
    service.start(username=username, password=password)
    return render(
        request, 'home.html',
        {
            'service': service,
        }
    )
def metrics(request, service):
    metrics = service.get_metrics()
    return render(request, 'metrics.html',
    {
        'metrics', metrics
    }
```

the code I would like or something like it:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(
        self
    ):
        super(User, self).__init__()
        self.usernme = ''
        self.password = ''
        self.service = ''

    def get_service(self, request):
        self.username = request.POST.get('username')
        self.password = request.POST.get('password')
        self.service = Service()
        self.service.start(username=self.username, password=self.password)
        return render(
            request, 'home.html', {}
        )

    def metrics(self, request):
        metrics = self.service.get_metrics()
        return render(
            request, 'metrics.html',
            {
                'metrics': metrics,
            }
        )
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873691/how-can-i-redirect-to-a-different-url-in-django

Comment: in this case he have `data` out of functions, it is different @PaulCollingwood

Comment: doing the django tutorial again is probably the way tbh