# Django login not changing URL

Tags: django, authentication

I am using simple Django URL to log in user and send to a required page, but as user sign in URL does not change.

Views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return render(request, 'required.html')
```

The URL does not change it remains `http://127.0.0.1:8000/myApp/login/`

How to change the URL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I redirect to a different URL in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873691/how-can-i-redirect-to-a-different-url-in-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it won't redirect as you are returning the result of a render so replace your return with a redirection

```
return redirect('home') #where home is a name for a view
```

Comment: thanks it worked...only thing is since home is the name of view you don't need to put it in inverted comas it will be (home)